# Practice your micro-architectural skills

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture

I've googled a lot and can't find what I look for.

***I look for some architecture practice.*** I mean there are a lot of books about Design Patterns, but I want something like analysis of common mistakes in architecture of EE applications. All I've found - antipatterns like string concatenation or something else that can be found with help of FindBug or Sonar.

***How I figure it out:***

1. *Book* with next steps: task definition, wrong decision, why it is bad, right decision.
2. *Educational resources*. I heard there are such resources for testers. Some applications are opened for testing and each who want to learn testing can test it; and after some period discuss own result with other people or see the percent of bugs he has found.
3. Maybe other ideas?

***Why I think Design Pattern books are not suitable for me:***

A developer may know many design patterns from such books, but can be incapable of selecting the correct one for the specific situation. IMHO, this is because these books don't give you any practice, and fail to educate the reader as to which design pattern(s) should be applied to any situation. Those books just get you a ready solution.

***EDIT:***

There aren't any answers any more. So I want to expand my question:

I believe, no I'm certain that exist courses dedicated to improve architecture skills, show the common mistakes in designing of web applications and so on. Also I know that there are a lot of conferences linked with this subject.

*Advice me where should I look for them, please.*

Comment: Better ask on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are you aware of [these books](http://press.adam-bien.com/)? I suppose every Java EE architect should at least have taken a thorough look inside. But even the best books or tutorials will never take you far enough. Becoming a good architect is a bottom-up process. You have to know the dirty details first-hand to abstract from them later.

Comment: @kostja No, I'm not. But I'm not sure that I'm ready for this book, because I'm not event a senior. Any way, thanks!

Comment: @LutzHorn this question would be closed *very* quickly on Programmers.

Comment: @NickoleAbs : Very simple: Poltergeists; Copy and paste Programming; God Object; Not invented here; Anchor boat; Action at a distance; Lava flow; Hard Code; Golden Hammer; Spaghetti code; Error hiding. I've forgot the main last one. DO you want explanation for each of them? Applying those patterns will simplify your life for the short-term. Then you leave the project and let cry those who will try to rescue it on the long-term. (Also I don't really understand your question) (please notify @ me as I don't check for replies manually)

Comment: @user2284570 you are speaking about obvious mistakes, too obvious. Avoiding those anti-pattern is a rule. But I'm speaking about another situations. Situations when there are many ways to solve specific problem, and you should consider all pros and cons of all approach and choose the best, and argue why it is the best... In other words, the above anti-pattern will be helpful for beginers

Answer (score 4):

[Holub on Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059388X) is a fresh and interesting perspective on design patterns.

Lots of code. Lots of pro and cons, very hands-on and practical. I learn something new every time I re-read it.

It has been my go-to book as the "next step after GoF and Head-First Design Patterns". I love it, and it has been very well recieved by the ones who have tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Can I assume that you know how to create independent objects using Dependency Injection? If not, this would be an excellent are in which to cultivate reuse and create a more robust architecture. Using DI would be an excellent way to re-architect an existing solution. (Contrast that with much evolved code, which becomes brittle because of interdependency.)

While you're not looking toward Design Pattern books, I'd ask you to glance at [Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351) by J. Kerievsky.

Kerievsky takes you through some real-life refactorings which have titles like "Move Creation Knowledge to Factory." (It's "real-life" in that he uses actual code, not a contrived example.)

Finally, I have been encouraged in our recent use of Spring Integration as an Enterprise Integration Pattern. If you architect and implement even a modest project in Spring Integration, you'll get quite a lot of experience with both DI and EIP.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer? Something got messed up in the first few sentences.

Answer (score 2):

In my views what I think going through the  Class Diagrams of the Design pattern will help you a lot.

What more i will suggest is to take a brief of the Book "**Head First Design Patterns**". As per my experience this book has some very good example related to every Patterns which will help you in the pattern selection.

As per the selection of Design Pattern is concerned you can develop it by implementing more and more pattern in different scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read Head First, and want to consolidate those knowledges. That is why I started to look for excercises

Comment: Well in that case what i will suggest is try to rework on your previous code try to implement them in your previous Scenarios.

Comment: But in such case I need someone who can correct me, if I make a mistake. Yes, can do that, but I want to share my experience/ consult with others, people who also tries to improve their architectual skills. I guess that will bring quicker professional growth. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing enterprise applications, I'd recommend [Patterns of of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) when you're done with the basic design patterns.

It was written about ten years ago and some of the more modern things about how to shard tons of big data across cheap servers you will not find in there. The cloud did not exist when it was written. But it seriously discusses a lot of things that you won't find discussed elsewhere, and coins names / patterns for elemental building blocks of applications. I'd call it a classic rather than old.

See http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/ for an index of the patterns that are discussed.

Comment: I have the Patterns of Enterpires Application Arch.  It's a really good book.  +1 recommendation

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the role of an architect is defined differently for different companies and often has less to do with code structure and patterns and more to do with your business requirements and practices.  Employers seem to be more interested in what systems you might integrate into your solution or how you expect to interact with varous customers under conditions imposed by your company.

Correctly using a DI framework or design patern is something ever programmer should be able to without specific guidence from an architect, but researching and choosing which DI framework to use that might best fit your task is something an Architect might do.

They also tend to do more advanced impelementations--One of the better architects I worked with implemented the more difficult parts of our system, he wrote a custom Java classloader that loaded classes from a database and designed how it interacted with a GUI builder he designed so our customers could edit a GUI with Drag and Drop and we would save a .class file into the DB so it could instantly be loaded by all the client machines hooked to that server.

Some companies have different definitions than others--a company I worked with that did set-top cable box software had some architects that hardly programmed or had anything to do with software design, they were responsible for things like decomposing communication protocols and interacting with customers to help understand their problems (I viewed this more as Analyst work than Architect, but it was much more technical than most Analyst work I've encountered)

I guess I'm saying that an awful lot depends on the company you are working with.  I suggest you go to your manager (or an existing Architect) and tell him you are interested in such a path and ask how you should progress.

When asked pretty much this question, one of the Architects I've worked with said that it's something you are always working at--you don't study up and finish, keeping up to date all the time on as much as you can is your new job--Where others might read a book or play a video game, you should be reading articles about software design, installing and playing with new software languages/tools/libraries and learning more about the specifics of your business.

Comment: Reading stack overflow is also a great method to improve your architecture skills.  Being a architect is also teaching less experienced programmers good programming skills.

Comment: I would also really grok the SOLID programming skills:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29

Comment: @Daniel, I agree. But stackoverflow don't provide you the productive criticism. Means not always. And that knowledges that I get at stackoverflow isn't classified. It's greate resource to learn in some narrow region, but it isn't appropriate to systematic learning of wide arrea.

Comment: @Bill K, I agree. But when I learn new languages/tools/libraries it'll be much better if I'll follow some guidances/best practices. Also it'll be very good if I'be aware about common mistakes and bottlenecks. It's actually what I looking for. And THANK YOU for response

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Adam Bien's book

[Real world java EE 6 Patterns](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/real_world_java_ee_6)

You can download an introduction based on this book at java.net

[Real world java EE Patterns (pdf)](http://download.java.net/general/podcasts/real_world_java_ee_patterns.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is learning general good practices for developing applications.  Knowing design patterns is very useful as it is a type of a language, so if you call something a "Controller" or "Request/Response" that automatically tells other developers the patterns you are applying and how to use it/work with it.  Also, large software is typically built using them, so **you have to know design patterns**.  Doesn't mean you need to squeeze every single one into every application, just saves you the trouble of solving problems others have already solved.  As far as best practices at code level, [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) is a good code analysis tool that taught me tons of do's and don't's.

Second, you need to narrow down the context and determine what types of applications are you planning on architecting. For example, web applications have different architecture from embedded applications, if you specialize in one you don't necessarily need to know all the ins and outs of the other.

Third, read up on [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007MQLL4E).

Fourth, do hands on work with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). It's a Java enterprise integration framework, great documentation and really easy to get up and running.

Comment: when I posted this question, I imply some own awareness in Design Patterns. Yes, I don't denied that I should know some design patterns. And thank you for the book :)

Comment: Never heard about Apache Camel, plus interesting book. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To me design patterns look like solutions to isolated problems. In real practice we have to deal with combinations of problems, which are highly dependent. I have never seen any pattern used purely. I can recommend one book which gives a wider view of software architecture: [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). It says how to approach to software design, instead of giving a set of common tools. With some examples it explains how to solve a set of problems in combination.

One more book gives an explanation on how to design classes and their collaboration: [Interface Oriented Design: With Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976694050). To write good understandable and maintainable code. It explains a lower level approaches rather then DDD.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents :)

1. I agree with your observation that simply learning design pattern is of little consequence. A typical thing which generally occurs after learning design patterns is that the developer tries to [map the a ready made solution (pattern) to a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717209/gather-info-from-xhtml-in-java-parser-visitor/16718848#16718848) which is not the right way and will create more problems than what it solves.
2. IMHO, being an architect is more a matter of experience than academics. An architect is at core a **Problem Solver** or **Solution Provider**. By problems, I mean the large scale design problem and not the day today programming problems.
3. The problems could be from whether to use [OR mapping tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) or not to larger and more profound problems like whether to go for [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) or not and likewise. Its not about WHAT to do but HOW to do.
4. These things are a matter of experience. A problem can be solved by thousand different ways but while designing a system, due consideration should given to technical feasibility, performance, scalability, deployment, maintenance, extensiblility and many such **non-functional requirements**. Now unless you have been-there-done-that, its difficult get hold of these things which are very vital for today's software system .
5. Nobody can deny the importance of books(*apologies for not introducing to new books as people here have already suggested wonderful books*). They are written by very intelligent, sharp and most important experienced, people. I view this as a way of sharing once's experience and view point and they help you in chalking your path.
6. Apart from books, the other very important way to understand or learn about system design is  ability to **dissect the existing systems**. For example, you might want to explore how a typical web server like Tomcat works or a DI framework like Spring works. Open source makes these things possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best single way to be a great software architect, developer, or programmer is to work.

Get the basics down, and then work on something - especially something you are interested in.  Hard work will pay dividends in the form of experience.

Surround yourself with people smarter than you, and listen to what they have to say.  Trust that their experiences can help lead you into a better understanding.

Wisdom is not something that can be bought with a $50 book, or even a $100K college degree.  Software craftmanship is something that you must earn.

If you have free time, working on a popular and **successful** open source project will help you gain great experience.

Comment: I agree. I want to earn it. The question it how to make it quicker. And about surrond me with clever people, yes, but it doesn't exclude self-study.

Comment: Very true.  Regarding self study, it gets complicated.  Ideally, you could work on a popular opensource project written in java.  I don't know of a popular one. Maybe someone else does.